# Find the critical points of the function $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}\sin (xy).$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, vector-analysis

Find the critical points of the function $f :\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by : $f(x,y)=e^{-xy}\sin (xy).$

**My attempts :** we have $\nabla f(x,y)= e^{-xy}\begin{pmatrix}  -y\sin(xy)+y\cos(xy)& -x\sin(xy)+x\cos(xy) \end{pmatrix}$, thus
$$\nabla f(x,y)=(0 \quad0) \iff \begin{cases} y=0 \text{ or } \tan(xy)=1 & \\ x=0 \text{ or} \tan(xy)=1 \end{cases} ,$$
$\tan(xy)=1 \iff xy= n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{4},$ so if $y=0$, then $x=0$ and if $y\neq 0$, then $x=\frac{1}{y}\left( n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$ .

Thus $(0,0)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{y}\left( n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right),y\right)$  are the critical points.
Thanksin advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computations are correct. On the other hand, the way you express the answer is not very clear. For instance: what is that $n$?

I would say that the set of critical points is$$\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}\cup\left\{\left(\frac1y\left(n\pi+\frac\pi4\right),y\right)\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb Z\wedge y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much Sir !